# Is it unsafe/inefficient to create ClientContext within repository methods (SP 2013)?

Tags: 2013

I'm doing the backend for a new .NET to Sharepoint integration and I would like to hide Sharepoint Implementation details from my team.  In this example (http://www.bugfree.dk/blog/2010/01/18/sharepoint-list-access-using-the-repository-pattern/) The author passes the SP.Web object to his repository methods, but I don't like how that requires the calling code to know a lot about sharepoint.

My question is whether creating the context inside each repository is A Bad Thing.  It definitely appears that it could be an expensive operation, but I'm new to SharePoint and not sure how to find the answer.

```
public class EmployeeRepository : ListRepository
{
    public EmployeeRepository()
    {
        Definition = new EmployeeDefinition();
    }

    public void Create(Employee e)
    {
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SharePointService.server))
        {
            SharePointService.SetCredentials(context);
            var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Definition.ListName);

            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreate = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem newItem = list.AddItem(itemCreate);
            newItem[EmployeeDefinition.EmployeeId] = e.Id;
            newItem[EmployeeDefinition.Name] = e.Name;
            newItem[EmployeeDefinition.HireDate] = e.HireDate;
            newItem[EmployeeDefinition.Remarks] = e.Remarks;
            newItem.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
// ...
}
```